# Array of arrays of truthy values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
const a = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true]
```

and i would like the `false` values to be removed and the resultant should look like sequence of `true`s

```
[[true, true], [true], [true, true], [true, true, true]]
```

can someone help with solving this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Because you didn't. answers will be voted down by ppl who believe answers to questions without effort needs to be punished as a lesson

Comment: Adding your attempts in your question will help others to understand what you have done till now and help you where you are facing issues, I suppose helping others is main pospose of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reduce and filter

```js
const a = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true]
const b = a.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  if (cur === false) acc.push([]); // add a new empty array
  else acc[acc.length-1].push(cur); // push the true 
  return acc;
},[]).filter(item => item.length != 0)
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `for` loop.

```js
const a = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true];

const res = [];
for (let i = 0, j = -1; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (!a[i]) j = i;
  if (!a[i + 1] && j < i) {
    res.push(a.slice(j + 1, i + 1));
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach with a single loop, using `slice` for a shorter code

```js
const a = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true]
const result = [];

let idx = 0;
let lastIdx = 0;
// to work when the array doesn't end with false
// you can also do this after the loop without mutating the array
if (a[a.length - 1] === true)
      a.push(false)
while ((idx = a.indexOf(false, idx)) !== -1) {
  const arr = a.slice(lastIdx, idx);
  if (arr.length > 0)
    result.push(arr);
  lastIdx = ++idx;
}

console.log(result)
```

No mutation:

```js
    const a = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true]
    const result = [];

    let idx = 0;
    let lastIdx = 0;

    while ((idx = a.indexOf(false, idx)) !== -1) {
      const arr = a.slice(lastIdx, idx);
      if (arr.length > 0)
        result.push(arr);
      lastIdx = ++idx;
    }

    if (a[a.length - 1] === true)
      result.push(a.slice(a.lastIndexOf(false) + 1, a.length))
      
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

fun challenge.
lots of others have already posted their solutions, might as well chime in:

this uses a simple for loop and some variables to keep track of whether or not a new sub array of true values needs to be created.

nothing fancy, though.

EDIT: wrapped the thing in a function because that's way nicer.

```js
const a = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, true, true]

console.log(dump_the_falsies(a))

function dump_the_falsies(array){

  let result_array = []
  let last_value = false
  let current_true_set_key = -1

  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        let val = array[i]
        if(val === false){
            last_value = false
            continue;
        }
        if(last_value === false){
                  current_true_set_key += 1 
                  result_array[current_true_set_key] = [val]
        }else {
                  result_array[current_true_set_key].push(val)   
        }
        last_value = true
    }
   return result_array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Declarative programming** *Approach:*

- turn array into a string using `JSON.stringify`
- split it by flase values
- use regex to get only true values using `filter` and count them using `map`
- create inner-arrays based on the counts of true vlaues.

*code & output of each step:*

```js
JSON.stringify(a)
//'[false,true,true,false,true,false,false,false,true,true,false,true,true,true]'
.split('false')
// ['[', ',true,true,', ',true,', ',', ',', ',true,true,', ',true,true,true]']
.filter(trues=>/true/.test(trues))
// [',true,true,', ',true,', ',true,true,', ',true,true,true]']
.map(arr=>arr.match(/true/g).length)
// [2, 1, 2, 3]
.map(times=>Array(times).fill(true))
// [[true,true],[true],[true,true],[true,true,true]]
```